# File Object is Not Getting Created

Tags: android, android-file

I am giving file browser to user to select file. On onActivityResult I am getting file path as - /file/sdcard/Android/data/com.coca_cola.android.conferenceapp/cache/Conference/export.txt. When I try to create file object on this I am not able to create. When I remove /file/ and create file object on sdcard/Android/data/com.coca_cola.android.conferenceapp/cache/Conference/export.txt its getting created. But I cant hardcode to remove /file/ from filepath as on other device it will be giving some other path. below is the code

```
private void readContactFromFile(String path) {
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        String st = "/file/sdcard/Android/data/com.coca_cola.android.conferenceapp/cache/Conference/export.txt";
        File file = new File(st);
        if (file.exists()) {
            Log.v("TTT", "file exist");
        }
        Log.v("TTT", file.toString());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            Log.i("Test", "text : " + text + " : end");
            text.append('\n');
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and I am getting path on OnActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        switch (requestCode) {

            case REQUEST_PICK_FILE:
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String path = data.getData().getPath();
                Log.v("PATH", path);

                readContactFromFile(path);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I am calling for opening file browser

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");      //all files
    //intent.setType("text/xml");   //XML file only
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"), REQUEST_PICK_FILE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

How can I get the perfect path or How can I remove this issue?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please edit your question and post the `startActivityForResult()` call that is triggering this `onActivityResult()` call.

Comment: I did. Please check in edits

Answer (score 1):

Because of the circumstance that the path differs on different devices you should use the frameworks api to retrieve the appropiate path for you.

Have a look at the [Environment class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html).

Comment: Exactly what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using hardcoded string path get the path using Environment class

```
File file=new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())+"YOUR_REQUIRED_FILE_PATH");
```

It will not defer from device to device.
Hope this helps :)